# Update multiple SQL columns using PUT method in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

In Python flask, if I want to update data in the Postgres database table, the below put method works. In the below code Using 'if condition' I am checking and updating the values for three columns ie for fname, lname, address.

My question is if I want to update more columns example 30 to 40 columns, should I write multiple individuals 'if statement' or Is there any optimized way to update more columns?

```
class TodoId(Resource):
    def put(self,email):
        data = parser.parse_args()

    todo = Model.query.get(email)

    if 'fname' in data.keys():
        todo.fname = data.get('fname')
    if 'lname' in data.keys():
        todo.lname = data.get('lname')
    if 'address' in data.keys():
        todo.address = data.get('address')

    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a generic update method:

```py
class TodoId(Resource):
    def put(self,email):
        data = parser.parse_args()

    todo = Model.query.get(email)

    for key, value in data.items():
        if hasattr(todo, key) and value is not None:
            setattr(todo, key, value)

    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: It partially works. But the problem is, the keys from data dict that are matching with the todo are updated correctly, but the rest of the values in todo are updated as NULL

Comment: What values do you expect in that case? NULL seems ok, when key was not passed in data

Comment: I have ten columns in a table and if I want to update only two columns, should I pass key-value for the remaining 8 columns in JSON object for PUT action?

Comment: No, only with 2 you want to update

Comment: In my case, I have a Postgres table with columns such as 'email', 'fname', 'lname', 'address'. My scenario is, I want to update only the 'address' field. In my JSON, I pass  'email' and 'address' as key-value in the PUT request. After the request execution the fields fname, and lname fields in Postgres update as null. How should I code if I want to update only the email and address and keep fname and lname actual value?

Comment: I am not sure, how the data structure looks like after parsing but I modified my code to skip null values.

Comment: Great... after changing the code... it's working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "update" method and pass the data object to it.

```
class TodoId(Resource):
    def put(self,email):
        data = parser.parse_args()

    Model.query.get(email).update(data)
    db.session.commit()
```